# How to animate the needle of the gauge in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to animate the needle of my gauge made with the package "ggplot2". I've already try with the package "gganimate", but I don't understand how to use it exactly.[The gauge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NF70.png).

What I'm trying to do is to start the needle in the red section of the gauge and make it go to the number I sent to it. It goes to 0% to 100%, each section have 1/4 of the gauge.

Here's the code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gganimate)

gg.gauge <- function(pos) {
  breaks <- c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100)  #Distance between color section in %

  #Calculate the ray of each circle
  get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.7,r2=1.0) {
    th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
    th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
    th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
    x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
    y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
    return(data.frame(x,y))
  }

  # Create gauge
  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(0, 25),aes(x,y),fill="red")+                         #Red section
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(25, 50),aes(x,y),fill="orange")+                     #Orange section
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(50, 75),aes(x,y),fill="gold")+                       #Yellow section
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(75, 100),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+               #Green section
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(0, 100, 0.993, 1.01),aes(x,y),fill="black")+         #Black periphery superior
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(0, 100, 0.70, 0.72),aes(x,y),fill="black")+          #Black periphery inferior
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(0.7, 0),aes(x,y),fill="black")+                      #Black based under red
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(100, 99.3),aes(x,y),fill="black")+                   #Black based under green
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(0, 100, 0.3, 0),aes(x,y),fill="black")+              #Half black cercle
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-0.60, pos+0.60, 0.1, 1.1),aes(x,y))+             #Needle
    annotate("text",x=0.88,y=-0.1,label="Growth",vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    annotate("text",x=-0.84,y=-0.1,label="Defensive",vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) 
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should take a look again at a couple ggplot tutorials: you almost certainly don't want to be calling `geom_polygon` multiple times, but to instead have data you can map onto encoding such as position. That doesn't address the animation part, but jumps out to me right away

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to R, but I'm gonna take the advice and look for some tutorial for "ggplot". Thank you.

Comment: The package docs are pretty thorough, and they link to resources by the package authors, such as [this one](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one implementation of something similar to what it sounds like you are trying to do. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)

get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.7,r2=1.0) {
  th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
  th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
  th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
  x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
  y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
  return(data.frame(x,y))
}


one <- get.poly(0, 25)
one$color <- "red"
two <- get.poly(25, 50)
two$color <- "orange"
three <- get.poly(50, 75)
three$color <- "gold"
four <- get.poly(75, 100)
four$color <- "forestgreen"
five <- get.poly(0, 100, 0.993, 1.01)
five$color <- "black"
six <- get.poly(0, 100, 0.70, 0.72)
six$color <- "black"
seven <- get.poly(0.7, 0)
seven$color <- "black"
eight <- get.poly(100, 99.3)
eight$color <- "black"
nine <- get.poly(0, 100, 0.3, 0)
nine$color <- "black"

all_ten <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:100){
  ten <- get.poly(i-0.60, i+0.60, 0.1, 1.1)
  ten$state <- i
  all_ten <- all_ten %>% 
    bind_rows(ten)
}



all_ten$color <- "black"

all <- one %>% 
  bind_rows(two,
            three,
            four,
            six,
            nine)


ggplot(all_ten, mapping = aes(x,y))  +  transition_time(state) + geom_polygon(all, mapping = aes(x,y, fill = color)) +
  annotate("text",x=0.88,y=-0.1,label="100",vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
  annotate("text",x=-0.84,y=-0.1,label="0",vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
  coord_fixed()+
  theme_bw()+ geom_polygon() +
  theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank()) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "forestgreen", "gold","orange","red")) + guides(fill = F) +
  labs(title = 'Gauge Value: {frame_time}')
```